# If the product of $x$ positive integers is $n!$ What is the smallest possible value their sum can have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> If the product of $x$ positive integers is $n!$ What is the smallest
>   possible value their sum can have?

I was wondering what could be the most efficient strategy to solve this problem for sufficiently small values of $x$ and $n$.

For example, if $x=4$ and $n = 10$,the smallest sum would be that of $40,45,48,42$ such that $$40 \times 45 \times 48 \times 42 = 10!$$ and hence that required answer is $$40+45+48+42=175$$However,I used pure brute-force approach  to get this result,I am inquisitive about a general strategy for this problem.

Comment: Have you tried Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @DJC:I have just started taking my multivariable calculus lessons,we haven't yet reached there.

Comment: Was this question brought up in the multivariable class or somewhere else?

Comment: @DJC. That gives a lower bound of $\lfloor x\sqrt[x]{n!} \rfloor +1$ but it's weak.

Comment: @ DJC:No,but from my quantitative aptitude modules.

Comment: I think you should just split $n!$ into prime factors, and make each prime a separate term (a single prime may repeat many times). For example, $6!$ should be written as a product of $2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5$. The sum then is $2 \cdot 4 + 3 \cdot 2 + 5 = 19$.

Comment: @Srivatsan Narayanan:Both $x$ and $n$ are inputs.

Comment: @FoolForMath Apologies. I misunderstood that I can pick $x$ however I want. The previous comment answers that question, not yours.

Comment: @Srivatsan Narayanan:No problem.

Comment: @Byron Schmuland:We have to find that at-least number.I have edited the question,I hope it's clear now :)

Comment: Nice problem.  Exact answers are probably hopeless, but good bounds should be possible because of insensitivity near the minimum.

Comment: Alternatively stated we want an $x$-partition of the multiset of prime factors of $n!$ that minimizes a function on it (multiply together all elements in the parts and sum the products).

Comment: An upper bound for the case $x = 2$ is given by the numbers in [this OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A127180).  Unfortunately there's no formula.  They are not much larger than $2 \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$, though, giving evidence to the comment of  André Nicolas.

Comment: $10!^{1/4} = 43.65$ so it seems natural to choose the numbers close to $43.65$ which don't have any prime factors larger than $10$. This gives your set right away.  I don't see if this can be generalized but it at least might help transform "brute force" into "intelligent brute force".

Comment: Also, a quick proof that the particular set you gave is the best possible: to minimize $x+y+z+w$ subject to the constraint $xyzw=C$, you take $x=y=z=w=C^{1/4}$. (Use Lagrange multipliers if you've seen them; in any case this should seem reasonable.) So you can't do better than a sum of $4(10!)^{1/4} \approx 174.6$; in fact $40+42+45+48 = 175$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the general idea is maybe not so bad. Just as a d-dimensional cube has the minimal surface area for a given volume of d-dimensional parallelopipeds (rectangular d-prisms in particular), we would want our numbers to be as close in value as possible.

The likely idea is that you would still take the prime factorization of $n!$, and then try to group the primes into $x$ different stacks that all have as close to the same product as possible.

One might ask: how does one go about finding out which primes are in which stacks? That's a great question. It sounds to me to be roughly as computationally challenging as the knapsack problem (e.g. [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)), which is NP-complete. But that might not be true. The advantage is that factorials behave sort of nicely, so 'most' factors should be able to be divided fairly equally for large n, low x. It's the few 'large' primes in the factorization that can mess everything up.

But at least this gives the brute forcing a direction of attack. This started as a comment but grew to an incomplete answer. But I'll think more on it and see what comes up.

Comment: This is a knapsack-ish problem -- the values you are trying to fit into the $x$ boxes are the _logs_ of the primes.  In regards to this, the large primes are not as much of a problem as you might think; greedy algorithms tend to work well.  And since you have large numbers of small primes (2 shows up ~n times in n!), you have a fair amount of "filler" to even things out.

Comment: To be specific, I am suggesting a greedy algorithm where you run thru the primes in order of decreasing size, each time multiplying the smallest of your $x$ numbers by said prime.

Comment: Another potential greedy algorithm: if we want to write $n$ as a product of $d$ factors, start by taking the factor of $n$ which is closest to (or closest to but above, or closest to but below) $n^{1/d}$; then write $n$ divided by that factor as a product of $d-1$ factors in the same way.

Comment: However, the algorithm I gave in my previous comment does not always give the optimal solution. Consider writing $14!$ as a product of four factors. $14!^{1/4} = 543.378$; the smallest factor of $14!$ greater than $543$ is $550$; the smallest factor of $14!/550$ greater than $(14!/550)^{1/3}$ is $567$; the smallest factor of $14!/(550\times567)$ greater than its square root is $546$. We get $550 + 567 + 546 + 512 = 2175$. But $560+540+546+528 = 2174$, and both sets multiply to $14!$.