# Sum of $2$ two-digits numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

> $X$ and $Y$ are two-digit numbers. If $Y=2X+2$  and $Y=2X$ in decimal and
>   octal system respectively, and unit digits of $X$ and $Y$ are $5$ and $2$
>   respectively, then how to find $X+Y$ in decimal number system?

**My attempt:**

I tried representing the two numbers in decimal as $(10a+5,10b+2)$ and in octal as $(8a+5,8b+2)$ and then tried to manipulate with according to the conditions $Y=2X+2$  and $Y=2X$, but they only give me one equation $b-2a=1$, how to get $10a+10b+7$(the sum of $X+Y$ in decimals) from these?

Comment: Equations are nice, but why not do a brute force search? You will be able to eliminate possibilities quite quickly.

Comment: Probably $X=(10a+5)_{10} \ne (8a+b)_8$ because the a's can be different.

Comment: @AndréNicolas:  I find 15, 25, or 35 for X with 32, 52, or 72 for Y (respectively) all work.

Comment: @GarouDan:  $b$ it the leading digit of $Y$, so the relations are $10b+2=2(10a+5)+2$ and $8b+2=2(8a+5)$, which are redundant as MaX says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean "unit digits of $X$ and $Y$ are $5$ and $2$  respectively"?  I agree with you that $a$ can be any of $1,2, \text{or } 3$ (no higher or $Y$ will carry in octal) and there is no single answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** (shortened) We are told that the (decimal) units digit of $X$ is $5$. So the only candidates for $X$ are $15$, $25$, and $35$. (Anything bigger, when expressed in octal, then doubled, is not a two-digit octal number.) The specification that $Y$ has units digit $2$ is superfluous.

Check which ones of $15$, $25$, and $35$ work. They all do.

For a problem in which the numbers are so nearly pinned down, trying to use "algebra" can be a waste of time.  Before introducing symbols, it is useful to play with the numbers to get a concrete grip on the problem.

Comment: How$\space Y<64$?

Comment: @MaX: It isn't! Answer corrected.

Comment: +1,I like your approach but actually the answer is what I and Ross got there is not unique solution.Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarified myself before, so yes I noticed that, but you are not supporting the algebraic approach which according to the official solution is the *best* method. However, your answer has it's own value as it invokes lateral thinking than the usual algebra.

Comment: To deal with a *big* problem, we may need to devise a "general" approach. But this is a very small problem. Analogy: to solve the problem roughly how many primes are there less than $10^{30}$, we need to develop general theory. To solve the problem of roughly how many primes are less than $40$, we get our hands dirty and count.

Comment: I agree,and this is something me and my CAT-instructor don't often end up debating...what I meant it is in pure/applied mathematics we *always* try to develop a *general* approach so that when the constraints vary, (cont'd)

Comment: we could be able to solve using the same strategy, but as much I can see now quantitative aptitude is all about *particularize* and when I (often) try to *generalize* the problem I end up with problems like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65862) and end up  flustering myself.Really I spend lots of time in generalization (which may be I shouldn't ?!), but that's how we learn more, doesn't it?

Comment: *Two-digit* number problems, if not absolutely trivial tend to be particular, and don't readily generalize. Other digit problems, such as what is total number of $0$'s used in writing the numbers $1$ to $999$, do generalize.

Comment: Thanks, and I think we have [recent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80918/) on the similar topic.